# Adding the Facebook Like button to a Weebly site

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, weebly

How do I include the Facebook Like button on a page of my Weebly hosted website?

I went through all the steps to apply a "Like" button but couldn't get it to work. I don't know anything about actually building a website or code really and Weebly requires HTML if you're going to add a button.

Is it not working because the Like button code is JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Weebly has a [help page](http://kb.weebly.com/facebook-like.html) that deals exactly with the "Like" button. The first part of the tutorial walks you through generating the Facebook code to be included in your page. The last step of this part is important, because you have to choose the right type of embedding code—in this case *iframe*. (I think here is your problem, because the XFBML code doesn't work with Weebly.)

> **Select the iframe code and copy it.  This is important as the XFBML code will not work properly.**
>
> [image]

Then, the second part of the tutorial presents the steps you need to do to embed the code in your website.

Comment: It won't work anymore, because there is no iframe button left

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to the [Facebook like button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698783/facebook-like-button-not-working) question on Stackoverflow. The answer regarding a tool known as LINTER should do the trick! ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700317/198836).)

This is an issue on Facebook's side that has to do with updating their cache data for your web page.

---

**Update**:

I'm not too sure how one would get a Facebook like plugin button to work if JavaScript isn't allowed. I would contact Weebly and ask them what scripting languages can be used on your web page.

[Jake Rutter](http://www.onerutter.com/open-source/jquery-facebook-like-plugin.html) has a jQuery Facebook Like Plugin that you could try out. He has several demos as well as guide on how to implement the plugin. If you have any questions as to how to implement this plugin, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: More like the Weebly site doesn't allow JavaScript includes

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise Then I have no idea how she's going to get the like button to work on her web page if they don't allow JavaScript.  I'll update my answer with more solutions soon...

Comment: Or perhaps Weebly does something odd with JavaScript files/embeds

Comment: @Alex I know you may not be able to view this comment but hopefully if you check here again you'll see it.  I understand your answer completely but the only thing that I don't understand is HTML5 is selected in the dialog box and not XFBML.  Perhaps they meant XFBML **AND** HTML5 won't work... maybe?  Great answer anyways.

Comment: @Mike Yes, that's what they meant, XFBML and HTML5 won't work. If you look at their tutorial, the pasted code (two more steps further) is with _iframe_.

Comment: @Alex I read through the tutorial, that was the only thing that was confusing me.  Great answer by the way.  I'd give you +1 if I could...